# dlib and Qt: building errors

Tags: c++, qt, deep-learning, dlib

I have installed dlib to have the static library in my computer and i want to use it in a Qt project but the problem is, once the dlib library is linked to my project i can build it and display simple matrix from dlib namespace but if i try to define a deep learning network i got the following error.

```
/home/jimmy/Desktop/Connected_Robotics_Watson/workco/work/mainWindow.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::cpu::pooling::pooling()'
```

i am really lost on how to use with Qt.
Here is my .pro file:

```
QT += network
QT += widgets
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Connected


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui                        
-lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_videoio
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
PKGCONFIG = dlib-1


# Input
HEADERS += mainWindow.hpp
SOURCES += main.cpp mainWindow.cpp
```

If i use the library with normal cpp code and use a cmake to compile, evrything works well.

Does someone have an idea on this problem?

Comment: Obviously your linker is crying again an undefined reference, which means that the static lib is not found. 
1/Did you first tried the normal way of adding a static lib ? 
LIBS += yourpath/yourlib.a
INCLUDEPATH += yourpath
2/Why do you the Configuration Features in your qmake ? (PKGCONFIG option ) ?

Comment: how did you install dlib?

Comment: @sandwood  when i tried to use the dlib simple functionality, like create a simple matrix and display it, it worked well. so why it could find for simple action but get undefined reference for others?
yes i have tried to add the library with the normal way and this time i got another kind of error. I use PKGCONFIG because in the pkcongif repo there is the metadata for the dlib library

Comment: @Aram i have installed the library with the following command:

`wget http://dlib.net/files/dlib-19.10.tar.bz2
tar xvf dlib-19.10.tar.bz2
cd dlib-19.10/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
cd ..`

Comment: @j.scho : correct, your Qt configuration must be ok if you can build some symbols of the library :  
I found this thread that is on the same probleme than you have, so it seems your issue is not related to Qt 
https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/371

Comment: @sandwood thank you for your link.
Yes i have seen this thread before so for the moment i didnt find a solution so i let this in standby and i move to a PyQt project where the deep learning is easier to use.
Thank you for your help